# Unable to pass constructed var inv as a parameter to another function in same class

Tags: python, inner-classes

Team: Need clarification: Unable to pass constructed var `inv` as a parameter to another function in same class. I am passing param on line 6 as `teamInventory.parse_inventory(inv)` but it is not getting intercepted by parse_inventory

can anyone correct me how to pass inv to `parse_inventory()` ?

```
class teamInventory:
    def clone_repo(self):
        self.team_dev = "dev0"
        for team_cluster in self.preprod_clusters:
            inv=str(local_repo_path)+self.team_dev+"/hosts.ini"
            teamInventory.parse_inventory(inv)
        return self

    def repo_checkout(self):
        try:
            local_repo_path.exists() and local_repo_path.is_dir()
            teamInventory.clone_repo(self)
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error %s : %s" % (local_repo_path, e.strerror))
        return self

    def parse_inventory(self, cluster_inv):
        self.server = "team"
        cro = teamInventory().clone_repo()
        if cro.team_dev in cluster_inv:
            print("dev cluster inventory")
        return self
avi.repo_checkout()
```

output

```
TypeError: parse_inventory() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cluster_inv'
```

expected

```
dev cluster inventory
```

Comment: `teamInventory.parse_inventory(inv)` should be `self.parse_inventory(inv)`

Comment: with that I get `return str(self) RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object`

Comment: You have a logic problem. `parse_inventory()` calls `clone_repo()` and `clone_repo()` calls `parse_inventory()`. How is this supposed to stop?

Comment: my intention to call `clone_repo` in `cr =teamInventory().clone_repo()` is only to access its vars not to actually run it. that is why am creating its object `cr` to loo on its vars.

Comment: Why does `clone_repo()` need to parse the inventory again? Can't it just copy the inventory directly?

Comment: I can fully simplify code but I was trying to understand the problem for my learning.

Comment: You need some way to tell either `clone_repo` or `parse_inventory` that they shouldn't call the other one, so you don't get infinite recursion. This could be an optional parameter.

Comment: figured out. thanks for all probes. I posted my changes as anwer. and it works great as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use self instead of referencing via class name and also removed the objects of other functions which were not needed.

```
class teamInventory:
def clone_repo(self):
    self.team_dev = "dev0"
    for team_cluster in self.preprod_clusters:
        inv=str(local_repo_path)+self.team_dev+"/hosts.ini"
        self.parse_inventory(inv)
    return self

def repo_checkout(self):
    try:
        local_repo_path.exists() and local_repo_path.is_dir()
        teamInventory.clone_repo(self)
    except OSError as e:
        print("Error %s : %s" % (local_repo_path, e.strerror))
    return self

def parse_inventory(self, cluster_inv):
    self.server = "team"
    if self.team_dev in cluster_inv:
        print("dev cluster inventory")
    return self

avi.repo_checkout()
```

Comment: partial credit of this answer goes to @barmer who commented to my question.

Comment: You also removed the call to `clone_repo()` from `parse_inventory()`.

Comment: agree, due to me being new I was thinking that is the way to reference to their variables.